# How to tell PyCharm to put generated functions below the current function instead of above?

Tags: python, pycharm, code-generation

I have a function call `foo()` inside my `main` function and the corresponding function `foo` does not yet exist.
I would like PyCharm to generate that function for me, using the light pulp option shown below.

It works in principle. However, I would like to have the new function generated **below** `main` and not before/above it.

=> How can I tell PyCharm to **put the generated function below** the function from which it is called/generated?

=> Is there some PyCharm setting that I could not find, yet? Or some plugin/extension?

[image]

If I **extract a method** (Ctrl+Alt+M), the newly generated method is put below the calling method, as expected.